# Exporting utility functions in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to do this (Pseudo code):

```
export const isDefined:Function<boolean> = ((value:any)) => {
    return !(value==null);
};
```

The `isDefined` function returns a boolean if the value argument is not null or undefined, and takes `any` type as an argument.  Thoughts on how to get it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recommendation: avoid using `Function` wherever possible. It erases type safety:

```
// these should error, but they don't
isDefined()
isDefined(1, 2, 3, 'too', 'many', 'args')
```

To save the type signature, get rid of the `Function`. Also may as well use `!=` for simplicity's sake:

```
export const isDefined = (value: any): boolean => {
  return value != null
}
```

As a bonus, you can abuse generics to make the function a little smarter. Here, the function uses a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) `T` to infer the type of what's being passed into it, then it uses a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to narrow the type in some contexts, e.g. an if statement. (Note: I defined it as a `function` to make it work in `.tsx` files. Single-generic arrow functions can't be parsed due to ambiguities with JSX.)

```
export function isDefined<T>(value: T | null | undefined): value is T {
  return value != null
}

declare const message: string | undefined
if (isDefined(message)) {
  message // here, message is string
} else {
  message // here, message is undefined
}
```

Comment: Very cool!  Could you elaborate a little on what the `value is T` part does?

Comment: That's the type guard part. I linked some docs for more info. If you call `isDefined` with `string | undefined`, `T` becomes `string`. Using this feature, TS will "smart cast" the type of the variable depending on what the return type of the function would be.

Comment: Great thanks - Do you know whether it's still possible to indicate the function return type?  Just curious ...

Comment: Well, it's already indicated. `value is T` is just a smarter version of `boolean` ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: `null` !== `undefined`.  I wouldn't check for `null` in a function called `isDefined`.  Otherwise, very cool!

Comment: Rename the function, then :P I usually go with `isNonNil` or something

Answer (score 0):

OK - Think I finally got it:

```
export const isDefined: Function = (value: any): boolean => {
  return !(value == null);
};
```