# What symbol/token set represents everything that is not null or undefined in javascript?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript, mocha.js, chai

I'm writing a unit test for the utility function:

```
export const isDefined: Function = (value: any): boolean => {
  return !(value == null);
};
```

So I want to verify that true is returned for all values that are true in Javascript.  Is there a set of values I can use that represent all such values?  Currently I'm using the set `[{}, "", 1]`Right now this is what the test looks like:

```
import { isDefined } from "utilities/utilities";
import { expect } from "chai";
import "mocha";

describe("isDefined", () => {
  it("should return false for undefined or null arguments", () => {
    expect(isDefined(undefined)).to.be.false;
    expect(isDefined(null)).to.be.false;
  });
  it("should return true for non null or undefined arguments", () => {
    expect(isDefined({})).to.be.true;
    expect(isDefined("")).to.be.true;
    expect(isDefined(1)).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

### Update

Function implementation with type guard from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51003292/exporting-utility-functions-in-typescript)

```
export function isDefined<T>(value: T | null | undefined): value is T {
  return value != null
}
```

Comment: Are you just asking about which values are [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)?

Comment: In a sense.  For example I'm assuming that [SMALLEST_POSITIVE_INTEGER-BIGGEST_POSSIBLE_INTEGER] can all be represented by the number 1 and that the test should pass.  I'm really looking for a set of values that represent all truthy values ... so effectively the test covers all edge cases ... This is partially an academic exercise ... It could be viewed as a question on the enumeration of entities that the isDefined function returns either true or false for.

Comment: @Ole see my comment below the answer. Try opening dev tools in chrome and in the console type: value == undefined then enter. You will get an exception. Type: typeof value === 'undefined' and enter. You will get true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
export const isDefined: Function = (value: any): boolean => {
  return !!value;
};
```

or if that's too magic:

```
export const isDefined: Function = (value: any): boolean => {
  return value == true;
};
```

This would also satisfy your test, but perhaps not your definition in your question.

```
export const isDefined: Function = (value: any): boolean => {
  return value !== undefined && value !== null;
};
```

This is what I would expect the function to do, based on it's name:

```
export const isDefined: Function = (value: any): boolean => {
  return value !== undefined;
};
```

**Edit**

Test-cases from a reputable source (MDN) for falsey and thruthy:

- [Thruthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)
- [Falsey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

Here's an official ecmascript source:

- [toBoolean in EcmaScript](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-toboolean)

Comment: I love these implementations.  Please leave them up.  What I'm really asking though is what exhaustive set of values / paramemters / symbols / tokens do we use to verify that  that the functions are working correctly in all situations.  For example I'm using {} for all objects, 1 for all numbers, and "" for all strings ... but perhaps I'm missing something that should be tested ...

Comment: I see. I guess you are looking for an existing set of test-cases that describe javvascript's definition of falsey or thruthy?

Comment: Yes - close - Actually existing set of values that can be used to test the semantics of whether something is truthy or falsey in javascript.  For example [null, undefined] ... that set is falsey ... [1, true, "", {}] ... all truthy ... but what other values should be in these sets in order for the set to exhaustively represent all cases ...

Comment: @Ole I added a couple of sources, hope it helps!

Comment: Awesome - Thanks!

Comment: @Evert Just a pointer on the answer above. The safest way to check if a value is defined/undefined is typeof value === 'undefined'; reason being is the above works fine when checking a value on an object but fails when check a value that has never been declared.

Comment: Good point @Andrew, would that even be the case for a function argument? Maybe when the argument isn't passed?

Comment: See my comment under the question. It would be the same for a function arg. The issue is caused because the variable being tested is not declared.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comments, I would write the function you are after like so:

```
function isUndefined(value) {
  return typeof value === 'undefined';
}

function isDefined(value) {
  return !isUndefined(value);
}
```

I'll leave it to you to translate to es6.

In terms of your original question about the set of defined values, you are correct in what you suggested about testing 1 and not worrying about the rest of the integer set.

In TDD this is commonly known as an equivalence partition. You are really aiming to test on the boundaries of equivalence partitions as this is where bug tend to manifest.  Another good test at least for numbers would be -1 as this is on the other side of the 0 boundary.

In terms of your tests, you should really try to ensure you have a single assert per test or at least a single logical assert i.e. all expect statements are testing for the expected state after the method under test has been called. I see in your tests you are testing some truthy and some falsy things in each test. Your test names could be clearer and the test could be better examples of the intent given by your test names. Other things to test for isDefined would things like array, string, object property. I can't think of anything else straight of the top of my head.

Comment: Very cool - appreciate the additional thoughts.  An OP also also provided a very good typescript implementation of the function here (Figured I'd reference it for completeness): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51003292/exporting-utility-functions-in-typescript